# Haskell SDL on OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, sdl

SDL on OS X uses preprocessor tricks to overload main() with their own entry point, written in Objective C, which calls the user's main.

These tricks make the lives of non-C SDL users (e.g: the Haskell bindings) very difficult.

Is there a good reason for this?

Why couldn't SDL do the objective-C Cocoa initialization in SDL_init?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach for Mac OS X is not much different from the approach for other non-Linux platforms (Windows, old Mac, BeOS). You could ask the SDL developers themselves why they did it this way, but I can see several reasons they may have chosen to do this:

- This keeps the dependencies of SDL code, which is focused on initializing SDL-specific subsystems (video, audio, timing, etc.) limited to the specific subsystems that SDL is especially designed to work with. I.e. this way, SDL stays lean and mean.
- It avoids having to introduce a new platform-specific subsystem for application initialization. Not everyone is going to want the bare-bones application object and menu that SDL sets up for Mac apps, not by a long shot – so if you were going to put it into `SDL_init`, you'd need to make it an optional subsystem so as not to inconvenience developers who don't need it.
- It handles inversion of control correctly, which is how Mac OS X and other application frameworks typically operate, while maintaining the operational semantics of SDL routines. SDL_init assumes it's going to be returning to the caller after initialization is complete, but if you tried naively to create an application object  in `SDL_init` and invoke `[app run]` on it to finish initializing the application and launching, you'd never return. If you didn't call `run` there, you'd have to create a separate SDL function to set up the application run loop. This could complicate the SDL library quite a bit. The approach that was chosen avoids all this, by letting the framework take care of all the application set up first, and invoke the `SDL_main()` routine from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.
- It makes it easy to convert SDL demos coded on Linux over to Mac OS X. You don't even have to rename main – the preprocessor renaming of `main()` to `SDL_main()` takes care of that for you!

I'm guessing the last of these reasons is the primary driver behind the redefinition of main in `SDL_main.h`, which I agree is an ugly hack.

If you're prepared to give up that level of cross-platform portability for your library and apps, I'd suggest simply modifying your `SDL_main.h` to remove the following line:

```
#define main SDL_main
```

and removing the following from the `SDLMain.m` in your project:

```
#ifdef main
#  undef main
#endif
```

You shouldn't even need to recompile SDL if you do this. Note that `SDLMain.m` is already set up to invoke `SDL_main()` without the preprocessor hack, and nothing else in SDL is going to use this, so in this way you can you simply provide `SDL_main()` as your game's entry point.

If you want to go the other way, taking over `main()` yourself, you'd still want to get rid of the `#define main SDL_main` hack in `SDL_main.h`, but other than that, you're not beholden to the `main()` that SDL provides for you. First, note that `SDLMain.{h,m}` are not part of the library proper; you must include them separately in your project. Second, note the following comments in `SDLMain.h`:

```
/*   SDLMain.m - main entry point for our Cocoa-ized SDL app
       Initial Version: Darrell Walisser <dwaliss1@purdue.edu>
       Non-NIB-Code & other changes: Max Horn <max@quendi.de>

     Feel free to customize this file to suit your needs
*/
```

That sounds to me like an invitation to go roll your own if these aren't working for you, starting with `SDLMain.{h,m}` as a model. And if you're rolling your own, you can do what you want! For that matter, you could write the equivalent of `SDLMain.m` in Haskell, using HOC, if that's what you want. Unless you're a whiz with HOC, though, I'd keep it simple.